Webscraping with python | How to pass a hCaptcha
I'm trying to automate a task that i enter in a public website, from the brazilian government, and collect some public data from some companies. But when i am entering with selenium in the website i discover that it has a hidden captcha and idk how can i enter the website and insert the ID from the companies that i was searching.
In the first place i tried to enter with selenium and insert the ID to collect the data, but the website show a text "Prevented by Captcha protection. Robot Behavior." but what i am trying to do is to simple automate a process that a person insert manually, catch the data and insert in some sheet.
When i look for the HTML i see that there was a hidden "hCaptcha"
<div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="96a07261-d2ef-4959-a17b-6ae56f256b3f" data-callback="onSubmit" data-hcaptcha-source-id="button[data-hcaptcha-widget-id='018rf9z74lbc']" style="display: none;"><iframe aria-hidden="true" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="018rf9z74lbc" data-hcaptcha-response="" style="display: none;"></iframe><textarea id="h-captcha-response-018rf9z74lbc" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea></div>

theres the code that i am trying to create to solve my problem
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options.headless = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

def enter_Gov(cnpj):
    driver.get("http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/aplicacoes.aspx?id=21")
    time.sleep(5)
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@src='/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    cnpj_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#Cnpj')))
    cnpj_input.clear()
    cnpj_input.send_keys(cnpj)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/button'))).click()
    time.sleep(10)

CNPJ_list = ['33592510000154', '33000167000101']

for cnpj in CNPJ_list:
    enter_Gov(cnpj)


I am getting the same error since some days ago (in the same site). I was able to do the scraping successfully with undetected-chromedriver, and everything was ok.
But somehow now receita.gov is catching and showing the message "robot behavior". I tried a bunch of solutions like ip rotation with proxy, slow down the scraping with time.sleep(), but nothing works. I tried other library like seleniumbase, but still does not work.
My last try was adding arguments in the uc.ChromeOptions(), the defaults, and not work too.
Hope the fix comes as soon as possible.
